# How to use words in text to search MySQL table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am creating an application in which users can save seperate notes. Within a note, the user can identify the note's keyword. If that word is mentioned in another note, I want the application to create a link to the note where the word is a keyword.

Example:

note 1: "This is a note with the [keyword]" (keywords are identified with brackets)
note 2: "This is a different note, but the word keyword is mentioned"

Now I want to create a link at the word 'keyword' in note 2, that points to note 1.

When a keyword is entered, it is saved in a keyword table and linked to the corresponding note id. I don't have a good idea how to search through that keyword table when a user adds a note or existing notes are loaded. It doesn't seem to make sense to use ALL words for a SQL query, since that could create many, many queries.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you try to load all keywords in to a 2 dimensional PHP array that has note_id => keywords or keyword => note_ids and do the keyword search using an array search? By the way just wonder whats the logic behind making a link to a note that has the keyword. Coz I think there will be many notes with one keyword and vise versa. So that means your link is going to load a list of notes?

Comment: Thanks, that might be a solution! The logic is that keywords are unique words, so every keyword will only be linked to one specific note.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this solution but I have a problem. Since I use javascript, I get the keywords form the database using jQuery post. However, this is asynchronous, so I can not save the results from this request in a convenient array that can be used while loading the page...

Comment: Is that what you are saying is, because the Ajax call is asynchronous, you cannot get the data to be saved in an array and access the data? May be you can try "async: false" so everything else will wait until, this call is done.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality that you are asking can be implemented but the issue is intensive processing. I would suggest, first of all you should limit the maximum number of keywords for a note (say 3 or 4). Then for keyword mapping, instead of searching whole text in note 2 (i.e. the new note that is being added by user), first allow user to define keywords in note 2. 
Once keywords in note 2 are defined by user, those keywords can be compared with database keywords list upon submission and required links can be made.

Before accepting, ask user whether he wants those links to be inserted or not (Its possible that he may get 20 links but he only want to choose 3 or 4 out of those. You can also limit the number of links to be attached).

Suppose, if no match is found or user is not satisfied with links, then give option to redefine keywords and compare again.

This approach will reduce the complexity and will be easy to manage. It shall be user friendly too. Your idea has lot of space for brainstorming. May be that's not your aim, but as you ask for suggestion so I have given mine. :)

Comment: It makes sense, but I prefer that users don't have to define the keyword referers in note 2. The idea behind the application is "you have many notes, let me help you with understanding the relationships between your notes by finding where certain words in your notes are defined" (assuming that a user uses a keyword in a note where he defines that keyword).

Comment: OK. One thing is coming in my mind. There are so many words which are not important like this, is, the, a, an, you, etc. So, you may supply an xml along with your webpage which contains list of unimportant words. Then try to catch every word (i.e. separated by space) using javascript and compare with list in xml and make list of all other words. So, you can eliminate unimportant words on client side. Then upon submission you have to compare only important words.  You can add words to unimportant list periodically. I am just thinking to reduce server side processing. What do you think?